# Why won't this keyup event handler work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is bug with Keyup event in following code when we press eneter it works wit all browsers exept IE9 do you have sulution for this :

```
   // on 'enter' in any input field, do the search
$("input, select", _this.sbox).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) _this.doSearch();
});
```

Comment: Is the event not firing, or are you getting an error?

Comment: What is the `doSearch()` function?

Comment: check you console in IE9, maybe there is some error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property instead of `keyCode`, the property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`:

```
event.which == 13
```

Comment: jQuery normalizes `keyCode` and `charCode` into just `which`: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/